# boolean for loading different data

Tags: angular, ionic4

l am working on ionic 4 project. My project is getting data `json` from url content flights schedules . l did `button boolean` when users click on button shows different data form data url in same page . When l click l got same data it is not change

```
  Loadearlierflights : boolean = true;

      async getData() {


        const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
          message: 'Loading'
        });
        await loading.present();

          /// flights details for today ///

        if (this.Loadearlierflights===true) {
          this.http.get('xxxxxxx/airport.json?code=bsr', {}, {})
          .then(data => {

            this.test = JSON.parse(data.data);
            const parsed = JSON.parse(data.data);
            this.items = parsed.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data;
            loading.dismiss()


            console.log(this.items)

          }), err=>{
            this.test =err
            loading.dismiss()
          } 

                   /// flights details for yesterday ///

        }else if (this.Loadearlierflights===false) {
          this.http.get('xxxxxxxx/airport.json?code=bsr&page=-1', {}, {})
          .then(data => {

            this.test = JSON.parse(data.data);
            const parsed = JSON.parse(data.data);
            this.items = parsed.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data;
            loading.dismiss()


            console.log(this.items)


          }), err=>{
            this.test =err
            loading.dismiss()
          }

        }
```

html

```
<ion-button shape="round" (click)="getData()">load earlier flights</ion-button>

<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" > 
        <table>
            <tbody>
            <tr >
            <td > 
            <div *ngIf="item?.flight.airline.code.icao">
              <img src="/{{item?.flight.airline.code.icao}}_logo0.png"  (error)="handleImgError($event, item)" class="img-logo">

            </div>
            <div *ngIf="!item?.flight.airline.code.icao">
              item?.flight.airline.name
            </div>
              </td>
            <td text-left>{{item?.flight.identification.number.default}}</td>
            <td text-center>{{item?.flight.airport.origin.position.region.city}}</td>
            <td text-right>{{item?.flight.time.scheduled.arrival  * 1000 | date:"h:mma"}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
            <td >&nbsp;</td>
            <td ></td>
            <td text-center>{{item?.flight.aircraft.model.code}}</td>
            <td text-right [ngClass]='item?.flight.status.generic.status.text |Status'>{{item?.flight.status.generic.status.text|Status}}</td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
      </ion-item>
```

any ideas please ?

Comment: Let me understand the question first, you need to change the value of `Loadearlierflights ` variable after clicking on the button, right?

Comment: yes . basically my app when he is run he is load data immediately from url `xxxxxxx/airport.json?code=bsr` . After that  when user click on `Loadearlierflights` he will going to load data from url `xxxxxxxx/airport.json?code=bsr&page=-1` . l hope you get idea

Comment: So what should change your boolean here?

Comment: I have added an answer. please check. @pabloescobar

Answer (score 1):

There is mistake in if-else

use If as shown below

```
if (this.Loadearlierflights)
or 
if (this.Loadearlierflights === true)
```

Use else-if as shown below

```
else if (this.Loadearlierflights) 
or 
else if (this.Loadearlierflights === false)
```

Comment: what different ? l don`t see any wrong in if condition !

Comment: you using =, which is used to assign values, instead of === or == which are comparison operator

Comment: l did . it is same problem !

Comment: are you sure that your boolean variable is changing properly?

Comment: sorry l checked console now .  variable is not  changing properly

Comment: @pabloescobar please mark it as answer then (tick mark)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make your template’s click to point to a new method:

```
async getEarlierFlightData() {
    this.Loadearlierflights = false;
    await this.getData():
    this.Loadearlierflights = true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Loadearlierflights : boolean = true; // should me global

      async getData() {


        const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
          message: 'Loading'
        });
        await loading.present();

          /// flights details for today ///

        if (this.Loadearlierflights===true) {
          this.http.get('xxxxxxx/airport.json?code=bsr', {}, {})
          .then(data => {

            this.test = JSON.parse(data.data);
            const parsed = JSON.parse(data.data);
            this.items = parsed.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data;
            loading.dismiss()

                // Added this
                this.Loadearlierflights = false;

            console.log(this.items)

          }), err=>{
            this.test =err
            loading.dismiss()
          } 
                   /// flights details for yesterday ///

        }else if (this.Loadearlierflights===false) {
          this.http.get('xxxxxxxx/airport.json?code=bsr&page=-1', {}, {})
          .then(data => {

            this.test = JSON.parse(data.data);
            const parsed = JSON.parse(data.data);
            this.items = parsed.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data;
            loading.dismiss()


            console.log(this.items)


          }), err=>{
            this.test =err
            loading.dismiss()
          }

        }
```

Let me know if it works.